# Unexpected bitshift behavior in C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, bit-shift

I am currently trying to extract some bits from an address called `addr` with a 32 bit mask called `mask` into another variable called `result` as follows

```
int addr = 7;
int x = 0;
uint32_t mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
result = addr & (mask >> (32 - x));
```

I am expecting result to be 0 when x = 0, and this is confirmed on online bitshift calculators. however in C code, `result` is 1. Why is that?

Comment: The behavior is undefined. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3 *If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: What is type of `addr`?

Comment: This kind of question would greatly benefit from a [mcve].

Comment: @hyde Why? It is pretty clear without it. Should be a duplicate though

Comment: @EugeneSh. and you're right!

Comment: @EugeneSh. See the edit to see what I think was missing in the first version of the Q. Asker avoids such omissions most easily by providing a [mcve].

Comment: In case you wonder why it is undefined behaviour, consider the hardware.  For example on x86 (and probably lots of others) `The destination operand can be a register or a memory location. The count operand can be an immediate value or register CL. The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31.`  So you cannot shift by 32 bits because it is the same as shifting by 0 bits once the hardware masks the count value.

Answer (score 2):

You're performing an illegal bitshift.

Shifting by a value greater or equal than the size in bits of the left operand results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is documented in section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
>   of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
>   the right operand is negative **or is greater than or equal to the width
>   of the promoted left operand**, the behavior is undefined.

This means you need to check the value of x, and if it is 0 then just use 0 for the bitmask.

```
int x = 0;
uint32_t mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
...
if (x == 0) {
    result = 0;
} else {
    result = addr & (mask >> (32 - x));
}
```

Comment: @Clifford If `x` is 1 then we have `mask >> 31` == `0xffffffff >> 31` == 1

Comment: I need more sleep (comment deleted)!  An alternative is `addr & ((mask >> (31 - x)) >> 1)` then the check for x==0 is unnecessary (I think - still need sleep!)

Answer (score 1):

From the C standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
>   type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value
>   of the right operand is negative or **is greater than or equal to the
>   width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undeﬁned**